# Wrap the same control in a WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

in my WPF project I have a selfmade timeline visualization. Each row of a Grid is an hour (e. g. 9 am, 10 am, and so on) and from left to right, the minutes increase from 0 to 60.

Assume an event ranges from 9:50 pm to 10:30 pm. It is visualized by some custom control, that fits its Width and position to the corresponding time in the "timeline". Can I break the **same** control to continue in the next row? I know a Wrap panel does this, but only between two separate controls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom control probably consists of other controls, right? And GridView is probably not the best choice if you need wrapping, you cannot move some columns to the new "line". Instead you could visualize each event as e.g. StackPanel with some custom stuff etc. So you should basically include the break-line logic into your control, so that when your control doesn't get enough width it would move its internal elemnets to a new line. How about including a WrapPanel into your control?

You could also use a normal ListView if you want to bind to a collection of elements and redefine the internal collection control of the ListView, so that it positions items horizontally. So all your events would stack to each other horizontally and wrap when needed:

```
<MyCustomControl>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ItemsSource="{Binding ... my events ...}">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
      ...
    </ListView>
  </MyCustomControl>
```